# How to search exactly by first or last name or by first and last name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reactjs, search, mapping

There is a function, which accepts a text value on each input.

There is an array which is full of user objects

I need to map through the array and get exact values

For example, if I write 'H' or 'h' I will find only Hanna Montanna, for 'A' or 'a' I will get 'Alexander Castle' and 'Anthony Hopkins' and so on and so force

```
function foo(value) {
     // code here 
}

 const users = [{ name: 'Alexander Castle', age: 25 }, { name: 'Anthony
 Hopkins', age: 60 }, { name: 'Naomi Kempbell', age: 37 }, { name:
 'Hannah Montanna', age: 19 }];
```

Comment: "strict" values doesn't really mean anything in Javascript (though there is such a thing as "strict mode"). Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: For staters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I have done the following 
            handleSearch: function(event) {
                var searchQuery = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
                var displayedContacts = CONTACTS.filter(function(el) {
                    var searchValue = el.name.toLowerCase();
                    return searchValue.indexOf(searchQuery) !== -1;
                });
                this.setState({
                    displayedContacts: displayedContacts
                });
            }

unfortunately, I get not what I really want

Comment: @user7245021, post what you've tried in your question, not as a comment, so others can see it readily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be your solution:

```
function search(term, users) {
    term = term.toLowerCase();
    return users.filter(u => u.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(term));
}
const users = [{
  name: 'Alexander Castle',
  age: 25
}, {
  name: 'Anthony Hopkins',
  age: 60
}, {
  name: 'Naomi Kempbell',
  age: 37
}, {
  name: 'Hannah Montanna',
  age: 19
}];
console.log(search('a',users));
```

Comment: He did want upper case search terms to work too - convert `term` to lower case as well.

Comment: term now gets to lowercase as well

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is perfectly fine but there is no need to lowercase term parameter and replace it's value with same lowercase value. So simply you can write like.

```
function search(term, users) {  return users.filter(u => u.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLowerCase())); }
```

Comment: I think it's more elegant to declare the lowercase `term` *once* rather than do it for every iteration. (another thing to do would be to simply declare a new variable `lowerTerm` if the concern is parameter reassignment)